Why is Judaism not universally relevant?
Why are Noahide laws deemed sufficient for non-Jews while Jews are obligated to a distinct, more comprehensive system?

Sanhedrin 58b and 59a explain that gentiles who study the seven Mitzvot are considered like a kohen gadol, who undertakes the most holy service in the beit hamikdash. We have various traditions that a non-Jew can merit the World to Come for practicing these mitzvot and doing good deeds. While we are obligated to accept converts and treat them with kindness and the utmost respect, we do not attempt to convert anyone, with rare historical exceptions, such as in Yemen.
Makkot 23b shows Rabbi Simlai explaining that Jews have 613 mitzvot which we are obligated to learn and follow. This is why the seven mitzvot bnei Noach are not adequate for Jews.

Alexander Yannai converted Idumeans after he conquered them.

@YDJ And look what came from that (Antipater's and Herod's line, which caused untold damage to the Jewish people). Besides, there's good reason to suppose that this "conversion" was the partial acceptance of mitzvos that Canaanite slaves do.
